# How to apply statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.compare_j test for linear and log-linear models

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I'd like to apply `statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.compare_j` test for linear and log-linear models.
The linear model formula is

```
Sale_Price ~ Overall_Qual + Gr_Liv_Area + Neighborhood + MS_SubClass + Bsmt_Exposure + Roof_Matl + Misc_Feature + Overall_Cond + Year_Built + Bsmt_Full_Bath + Total_Bsmt_SF + 1.
```

Log-linear model formula is

```
np.log(Sale_Price) ~ Overall_Qual + Gr_Liv_Area + Neighborhood + MS_SubClass + Bsmt_Exposure + Roof_Matl + Misc_Feature + Overall_Cond + Year_Built + Bsmt_Full_Bath + Total_Bsmt_SF + 1
```

(same features, but `np.log(Sale_Price)` instead of `Sale_Price`).

When I run the test I get an error

```
ValueError: endogenous variables in models are not the same
```

**Is it possible to compare linear and log-linear models using this method? And does it make any sense** or no model is superior in this case?
Because if I try a workaround

```
log_model.model.endog = np.exp(log_model.model.endog)
```

I get

```
ValueError: The exog in results_x and in results_z are nested. J comparison requires that models are non-nested.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you are using a data frame, you need to create a new column with the log Sale_Price and regress using that:

```
df['log_Sale_Price'] = np.log(df['Sale_Price'])
mod = smf.ols(formula='log_Sale_Price ~ Overall_Qual + Gr_Liv_Area..', data=df)
```

As for your second question, you should not use `statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.compare_j` because the dependent variables are on different scales. This function should be implementing the [J test in R](http://math.furman.edu/%7Edcs/courses/math47/R/library/lmtest/html/jtest.html), so according to the manual:

> The J test statistic is simply the marginal test of the fitted values
> in the augmented model.

Since your predicted values from the log model would be on a different scale as the non logged, this will not work.

If I understood your question, you want to see whether log transformation of your dependent variable gives a better fit.

The primary reason for transforming the dependent variable is to ensure the residues follow more closely, a gaussian distribution. You can simply plot the residues versus the predicted values to check this relationship, for example in [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_transformed_target.html). Also you can apply [the Breusch-Pagan test](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan.html) and check whether it improves with the log transformation.

Comment: r-squared is invariant to linear transformation, but not for nonlinear transformation.

Comment: Point taken. I did not phrase it properly. You cannot really use it to compare the two models because the dependent is different. I wanted to say something like understand where the model does better at explaining the variance

Comment: Of course, we know that a single metric can be misleading.. and if it explains more variance, it might not be a better fit. Yeah let me remove that

Comment: statsmodels does not have good support for transforming the dependent variable. We would need a log-normal likelihood function and then Vuong test should work. To keep track of this https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7198